# a bash script to test service

Tags: batch-file, service, windows-services

I need a bat script for function like:

1. test if a service with specified name existed, if not, install and start the service.
2. test if a service with specified name is running, if yes, stop it, then remove the service.

I know I can install & start & stop & delete service using sc.exe, but how can I detect them ?

Comment: You mention bash, bat and sc.exe. So you to detect a service by name on Win with a batch file?

Comment: Use `wmic service`.  `wmic service list brief` will show you the current installed services.  `wmic service /?` provides help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wmic service`. 
`wmic service list brief` will show you the current installed services so you can pipe that to the find command.

```
wmic service list brief | find "<servicename>"
```

%errorlevel% will then be 0 if `find` found your servicename or 1 if it did not.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx for more info on `wmic`.

For stopping and starting a service, see http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2949/windows_use_wmic_start_stop_service_command_line.